# How to add logging to a webflux endpoint in spring-mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, reactor

I have an existing `spring-mvc` application with different `@RestController`. Now I want to add a `Mono<String>` endpoint, and log the request timestamp with url path, as well as the response timestamp.

But how? I cannot simply `@EnableWebFlux` as I would have to disable spring-mvc therefor.

How could I register a filter explicit for the webflux endpoint that catches on invocation, and right before the response is written back async?

```
@RestController
public class FluxService {
   @PostMapping
   public Mono<String> post() {
         return webClient.post().uri(uri).bodyValue(payload).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
   }
}
```

I want enhanced logging on the `@PostMapping` endpoint, not on the `webClient`!

Answer (score 0):

MVC is a blocking/servlet based api, mixing it with webflux isn't going to work.  They use different filters, security etc as MVC assumes a lot of ThreadLocal stuff. ([Can I use SpringMvc and webflux together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883037/can-i-use-springmvc-and-webflux-together))

If you really want to mix them like this you could use .doOnNext() once you get your mono and call your logger there.