# Reactive Spring Boot - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SHUTDOWN_QUIET_PERIOD

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-reactive

I'm attempting to migrate an old spring application to springboot 2.3.1 and spring 5.2.7. Goal is to make a reactive application. However I'm stuck on the below. I'm not entirely sure what else I need to upgrade.

This is part of my pom, other libraries are internal libraries, I don't think there would be any clashing though.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-spi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reactorClientResourceFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/function/client/ClientHttpConnectorConfiguration$ReactorNetty.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorResourceFactory]: Factory method 'reactorClientResourceFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SHUTDOWN_QUIET_PERIOD
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.esrx.Main.main(Main.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorResourceFactory]: Factory method 'reactorClientResourceFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SHUTDOWN_QUIET_PERIOD
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SHUTDOWN_QUIET_PERIOD
    at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorResourceFactory.<init>(ReactorResourceFactory.java:65) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.function.client.ClientHttpConnectorConfiguration$ReactorNetty.reactorClientResourceFactory(ClientHttpConnectorConfiguration.java:53) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: why are you dragging in a seperate version of spring (5.2.7) when spring boot itself 2.3.1 will pull in the spring core that is relevant for that release?

Comment: because of some company specific poms, there were clashing version of some libraries so I needed to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the **reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar** which has the constant **DEFAULT_SHUTDOWN_QUIET_PERIOD** defined in it's **LoopResources** interface.

The most important thing that I notice in your POM is that you have got both **spring-webmvc** and **spring-boot-starter-webflux** as dependency.

As explained in the Spring Boot reference documentation, **Spring Boot will auto-configure a Spring MVC application if both MVC and WebFlux are available since Spring MVC cannot run on Netty server.**

That is why **it is [advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883037/can-i-use-springmvc-and-webflux-together) not to mix the web dependencies with webflux**. If you are trying to build a reactive microservice, just use the **spring-boot-starter-webflux** and remove web, webmvc and all.

Also as @thomas mentioned, there is no point to separately include spring-core as it comes with all spring boot starter dependencies. To see that happening, use `mvn dependency:tree`  or `./gradlew :dependencies` and check the dependency tree.

Comment: I have to declare them explicitly because of some company configured poms that bring in different versions of some parts of spring. Thank you that was it!